# Html Attribute not populating from HttpContext.Items

Tags: c#, html, razor, asp.net-core

My problem seems fairly simple, and I feel like I'm missing something extremely obvious; but I'm unable to determine why the Nonce attribute on the script elements aren't populating and remaining empty strings instead.

I decided to use the Items collection inside the HttpContext to store the nonce because, from what I can tell, it is per request.

Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)

```
...
app.Use(async (context, next) => { //CSP
    RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] nonceBytes = new byte[32];
    rng.GetBytes(nonceBytes);
    string nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(nonceBytes);
    context.Items.Add("ScriptNonce", nonce);
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy", string.Format(
        "default-src 'none'; " +
        "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'nonce-{0}'; " +
        "style-src 'self'; " +
        "img-src 'self' data: https:; " +
        "base-uri 'self'; " +
        "upgrade-insecure-requests; " +
        "object-src 'none'; ", nonce));
    await next();
});
...
```

View

```
...
@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" nonce="@Context.Items["ScriptNonce"]"></script>
    <script src="~/js/Views/Admin/users_index.min.js" nonce="@Context.Items["ScriptNonce"]"></script>
}
```

Result:
[The Nonce is generated, it exists in HttpContext.Items, does not populate.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3KVa.png)

This seems really simple and I'm really confused on why the attributes are not populating.
I'm a bit new to web development so any tips in ASP.Net Core 2 would be greatly appreciated, if anything stands out to you.

Answer: [First Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52503381/html-attribute-not-populating-from-httpcontext-items#comment91951997_52503381);
[The nonce was there the entire time, chrome was hiding it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGNip.png)

Comment: Are you looking at the `nonce` attribute in the Elements tab of the Chrome Developer Tools? If so, look at it in the response returned from the server (in the Network tab) - you might be surprised. I just tried to reproduce your issue and found that it's all working fine, except that Chrome doesn't show the nonce value in the Elements tab (I believe this is a security measure).

Comment: Yes, does that cause problems? It works when I hard code the value.

Comment: I seen it, I couldn't figure out how to show it in chrome, but I opened it in fiddler and sure enough, your right. It was there the whole time. Thank you for pointing that out, I would of never guessed chrome was hiding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: [First Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52503381/html-attribute-not-populating-from-httpcontext-items#comment91951997_52503381);
[The nonce was there the entire time, chrome was hiding it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGNip.png)

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, Chrome simply removes the nonces from the debug window for security reasons.

However, unless you are creating inline scripts with your JS code, you don't need the nonce on scripts that are static files and being served from your filesystem (i.e. that are going to be requested by the browser separately).  The nonces are only used for inline scripts, to prove they are intended by the server ('self').

Same goes for styles, too.

You should also remove 'unsafe-eval' when you've created a nonce.  The unsafe-eval will mean the nonce is pointless.

e.g.

```
"script-src 'self' 'nonce-{0}';
```

And

```
@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/Views/Admin/users_index.min.js"></script>
    <script nonce="@Context.Items["ScriptNonce"]">
       console.log('hello') 
    </script>
}
```

To be clear: Some libraries, like jQuery and GTM created inline scripts in the head, which violate CSP unless they 'pass through' the nonces to the inline scripts they create.